# How to make angular-ui-router state showing backend data bookmarkable?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, restangular

I'm only working with angularJS since a few weeks, so I might miss something obvious.

My basic search+display app works with Restangular and ui-router as follows:

1) User enters query and clicks search

-> backend results get stored in $scope.results, results get shown as a list, 
url is now: ?query=foo

2) User clicks on one of the results

-> clicked item becomes $scope.active_item, router goes to detail view partial,
url is now: /show/1234?query=foo

Now I couldn't find anything about the angular way of making this resulting detail view url bookmarkable / linkable. When I reload the page $scope.results and $scope.active_item are empty, the backend data is obviously missing.

What I have done to make my search result bookmarkable was putting this into an init function:

```
var location = $location.search();
if (location['query']) {
  $scope.query = location['query'];
}
```

I was thinking of something like that for the detail view, but it just doesn't seem the angular way of doing things:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if (toState.name == 'show_detail' && !$scope.active_item) {
      // load single item based on the id in the url the and assign to scope
    }
}
```

What is the best practice for making states which rely on backend-data bookmarkable?

Comment: Have a look at the `resolve` feature and fire a http request in order to fetch the necessary data when the route is opened. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: Couldn't you just use the routerProvider to provide the parameters "foo" and "1234" to the controller from the page URL and then execute the query again on page refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query parameters are available on the `$stateParams` service, ex. `$stateParams.query`

To get the search results when going to the bookmarked URL use the `resolve` attribute on the state definition (see: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve for video walkthrough of resolve basics).

```
.state('search', {
    url: '/search?query' }) .state('search.detail', {
    url: '/show/:resultId?query',
    resolve: {
        results: ['SearchService', '$stateParams', function(SearchService, $stateParams) {
            return SearchService.get($stateParams.query);
        }]
    } })
```

There are a couple of gotchas here when it comes to bookmarking — the search would have to return stable results for this to work i.e. the same search always returns the same results, otherwise when the results change the item being shown may not be present.

For example item #3 from "events next tuesday" would be bookmarkable but not give useful results, but item #3 from "June 12 2013" probably would be more reliable (of course this depends what the search source is, deletions etc)